# Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error Every boot

Tags: gnome-software

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and getting the following error message
every time i boot

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.
If you notice further problem, try restarting the computer 

send an error report to help fix problem

show details / continue

details 

ExeceutablePath   /usr/bin/gnome-software
Problem type Crash ApportVersion 2.20.1-ubuntu2.10
```

Comment: Have you applied latest updates to your system ? In a terminal (`ctrl-alt-t`) run `sudo apt update` to update package repository, and `sudo apt upgrade` to apply latest updates.

Comment: If you have patience and if you can keep sending those error reports, you should. And I would highly recommend that you do. You should check out this [errors report page](https://errors.ubuntu.com/) for Ubuntu. As you can see, currently, the 2 most common errors are related to `gnome-software`. So you aren't the only one having these issues. Just keep your software up to date as @SorenA says.

Answer (score 3):

The reporting errors program (Apport) is known to complain about stupid things. One good solution, which is done by most Ubuntu users, is to disable that program.

However, before doing that, make sure that the Software application (which, according to the error report, has the problem) is working OK. Also, as Soren A commented, you should upgrade your system, in order to fix something that would be buggy.

If all of these things are OK, you can disable Apport by typing in a terminal:

```
 sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

(If that isn't working try: `sudo systemctl mask apport.service`)

After typing that command in the terminal, reboot your system.

Doing that should do the trick.

In case that my solution didn't work, you can try reinstalling Ubuntu (if you have no trouble for doing that) and seeing if the problem is still ocurring.

Comment: **No no no. Don't disable important parts of the OS.**

Comment: @heynnema Why would it be a problem to disable Apport?

Comment: @EliahKagan how would the average user know if something went wrong, and be able to report it, if desired? See my answer, further below.

Comment: @heynnema So you do not actually mean OS will *stop functioning* when Apport is disabled, do you? I'm reasonably sure that anyone who doesn't already know what you're trying to teach them will interpret "Don't disable important parts of the OS" to mean that. (That's really my only concern here.)

Comment: @EliahKagan no, I never intended to imply that the OS will stop working, but rather... don't disable all of the warning lights and gauges on the dashboard of your car... else how you going to know that you're about to run out of gas... or your alternator is on the fritz. Knowledge is power, and the more the user knows about what's going on/wrong with their system, the better the chance it'll get fixed, rather than ignored.

Comment: I never had anything useful coming out of apport that ever helped me to fix any problem

Answer (score 3):

[Soren A](https://askubuntu.com/users/614422/soren-a) posted a working solution [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951535/sorry-ubuntu-16-04-has-experienced-an-internal-error-every-boot/973577#comment1515829_951535):

> Have you applied latest updates to your system ? In a terminal (`ctrl-alt-t`) run `sudo apt update` to update package repository, and `sudo apt upgrade` to apply latest updates.

This seemed to be the simplest and least potentially destructive, so I decided to try it first. I have verified that the method of running `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install` fixed this problem for me.

Comment: This is really the best first approach in most cases and it will often solve the problem. Before attempting to figure out what is causing a problem--and *especially* before actually submitting a bug report--one should almost always install the latest security and stability updates available in one's release, which is what this method does. (One exception is, of course, when the problem is actually preventing updates from being installed.) I'm glad we have this as an answer, since for many if not most users, it *is* the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The **correct** answer is:

When you get a notification on your screen that something has crashed, check or un-check the option to send in an error report, and then click the **Continue** button. This will clear out the **current** crash notification (instead of getting notified of the same crash over and over).

The second part is... click on **details** and read the diagnostic text information, and find out why it's crashing and fix it.

Comment: @RoVo  Yes, **uncheck** the box, **but** hit the **continue** button.

Comment: I see, maybe I just click (x) automatically with such popups ... Why can't it be placed where it should be placed... In the notification area.... (okay, that's a different question).

Comment: @RoVo because it's a **system level** problem, and requires more action than a simple notification.

Comment: and annoy or confuse people so much that the common solution is to disable apport ...

Comment: @RoVo no, you **don't disable apport** just because you can't click the CONTINUE button. How else would you know that you had a problem, and, by reading the diagnostic text, how would you know how to go about repairing the problem?

Comment: Because mostly it's not important but just chromium or something like that crashed. And YES I noticed that it crashed, even without apport. And the crashlog is in /var/crash .... without apport. But let's stop the discussion ... It's getting very idealogical.

Answer (score 0):

In my position as a tech for a PC OEM, I see that when either:

- the package in question gets corrupted/deleted/mangled
- apport is the mangled package

I would recommend reinstalling by force the package that is messaged first.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-software
```

Try that first, then reboot.